# How to repeat or duplicate a unique row into a dataset?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This might sound odd, but a physical printing service we are using will take a SQL call, and print the returned rows.  We need multiple copies of the same physical print, so we have to make the same call 100+ times.  If we can somehow return a unique row, but identical 100 times in a call, it would save tons of processing.  We can't pass "# of copies" unfortunately.

So `select * from PendingPrints P where P.RecId = 12345678` would return:

```
ITEM     Serial#        Description       UnusedColumn1   UnusedColumn2
55555    2014021434567  "Fancy Widget"
```

And we just make that call 100+ times.  And I need it to somehow return in one call:

```
ITEM     Serial#        Description       UnusedColumn1   UnusedColumn2
55555    2014021434567  "Fancy Widget"
55555    2014021434567  "Fancy Widget"
55555    2014021434567  "Fancy Widget"
55555    2014021434567  "Fancy Widget"
55555    2014021434567  "Fancy Widget"
etc...................................x100
```

I have spare columns that are unused, or I could just create a counter I was thinking and that might work.  I was curious though if I could somehow use something like `Replicate` to repeat the rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate numbers with a recursive CTE (or some other method) and then use a join to get what you want:

```
with nums as (
      select 1 as n
      union all 
      select n + 1
      from nums
      where n < 100
)
select *
from PendingPrints P join
     nums
     on n.n <= 100
where P.RecId = 12345678 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Can add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` at end of query if you need more than 100.